# Filtering facets results in nested element with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this mapping:

```
products: {
    product: {
        properties: {
            id: {
                type: "long"
            },
            name: {
                type: "string"
            },
            tags: {
                dynamic: "true",
                properties: {
                    tagId: {
                        type: "long"
                    },
                    tagType: {
                        type: "long"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a facet on tag ids, but with tag-type filtering.
I need the filter to only apply on the facet and not the query results.
So here's my request:

```
{
"from": 0,
"size": 10,
"facets": {
    "tags": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "tags.tagId",
            "size": 10
        },
        "facet_filter": {
            "terms": {
                "tags.tagType": [
                    "11",
                    "19"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},
"query": {
    "match_all": {}
}
```

}

The facet filtering does not seem to affect the faceting.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter is applied to the documents, the parent entity in your example. That means that you're filtering the documents on which you make the facet by `tags.tagType`. Therefore all documents which have a specific `tags.tagType` value are used to build the facet, which is not what I want.

This is the usecase for [nested](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type.html) documents. You can have a look at [this nice article](http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/6/3/fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/) too.